# Computer (Amd64 Turion processor) not booting after instalition

Tags: ati, 64-bit

I have a machine running windows 7, and a laptop with a Amd 64 - Turion processor running Vista. So I tried to install Ubuntu on the laptop with Vista, runned the intalation CD after booting, everything went Ok, I selected the option to install Ubuntu and delete Windows... Selected everything, and during the instalation process the computer stalled...screen went black and everything stoped, then shutdown... When I turned on the computer again, it had no OS on it...neither one... Then I tried to reboot it with the CD again, he loaded but couldnt run the instalation again.

Can I try again Instaling with the CD (in some way) or did the PC go to heaven?

Comment: The PC is not in heaven, but there may be some BIOS options or something blocking the install. We need more info. What model computer? Which Ubuntu version? Error messages?

Comment: The computer is an Acer Aspire 1150 (series) with an AMD 64 x2 Turion Processor, 1.53 Ghz, 2.5 Gb Ram, ATI Radeon 1100 Express Graphics, and it had Windows Vista. And I am trying to instal Ubuntu 12.04.1...

Comment: Some correction to the information above:
Acer Aspire 5100, AMD 64x2 Turion TL-50, at 1.60 Ghz, 2.5 Gb Ram, ATI Radeon 1100 Express Graphics. As for the error message, I was not able to see one...
But meanwhile I was able to install it, and I done it by doing the following: I followed your above advice and looked for something on the BIOS, after confirming everything was ok I tried to boot from the CD, then selected the option to "Try Ubuntu without installing" and then instaled Ubuntu from there, just like ThiagoPonte advised me to try. Thanks to you both!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Ubuntu CD, before you install there are some options that could help you determine what's the problem with your laptop.

Boot the CD and when you get to the CD Menu, choose: Test Memory.
It will run MemTest+, it could take a while, something between 20~50 minutes, depending on the system.

You can also run Ubuntu without installing it.
Choose the option: Try Ubuntu without installing.
From there check if you can mount your Hard Disk with no problems.

Comment: Thank you Thiago. Well that seams to be the problem, the last time I tried booting from the CD after the installation crashed, the computer was not able to boot from there, one time shuted down, and the other time booted, but was blocked I couldn't do anything. I'm going to try "Shakabra"'s advice and see if there is something in the BIOS blocking the install.
Once again, thanks!

Comment: Thiago, once again, thanks, I was able to finaly install it, by booting from the CD, choosing the option "Try Ubuntu without installing" and then instaling from there. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer served you well, please choose my answer as correct.